# LINQ C# How to set an attribute as sum of other two

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say i have a list of object Cat { Name, Age, Size, Weight, etc.}. Now let's imagine a List cats. What i want to do is to create a new List of CatDataView:

```
cats.Select(cat => new CatDataView{
    Name = cat.Name,
    Age = cat.Age,
    Size = cat.Size,
    Weight = Age + Size})
```

Is it possible in some way to do this Weight = Age + size? This is for a more complex problem, where Age and Size are complex LINQ queries.

Comment: `Weight = cat.Age + cat.Size`?

Comment: I don't think anyone is actually reading `This is for a more complex problem, where Age and Size are complex LINQ queries.`.

Comment: @itsme86 then why doesn't he post these queries. We're only able to help with what he provides us.

Comment: @rango you have the code, but you didn't understood my question

Comment: @TobiasTengler I don't think it really matters what the actual queries are. You just need to know that they're complex enough that OP doesn't want to run them twice. That's the whole point of the question. How to assign a value to `Weight` without running the queries for `Age` and `Size` twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your "complex LINQ query" already got the values you want to add up into your model object, you could make the `Weight` property getter calculate the value instead of executing another query:

```
public class CatDataView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Weight => Age + Size;
}
```

The example property is using expression body, [introduced in C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6).

Answer (score 1):

Which part is complex? Just use it like this:

```
var result = cats.Select(cat => new CatDataView{
    Name = cat.Name,
    Age = cat.Age,
    Size = cat.Size,
    Weight = cat.Age + cat.Size}).ToList()
```

Comment: if cat.Age si a 5 rows query, and cat.Size is also a 5 rows query, it looks horrible to have Weight as a 5 rows queries + 5 rows queries. My question was if there was any way to sum those up, not the obvious way people jumped to conclusions.

Comment: I believe that you have horrible misundertanding about LINQ. SELECT is row by row operation.